# What is the partial sum $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^k}{2k-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a problem where, after some work, I've arrived at

$$6 \times \lim_{n \to ∞} \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^k}{2k-1}$$

and I need to find the partial sum $$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^k}{2k-1}.$$

to calculate the above limit, but I'm having trouble finding it.

I know that if this was simply a series with the $\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^k$ term, I would just use the geometric series formula, but there's an elusive alternating term as well as the $2k-1$ term.

Comment: It is likely that the limit can be stated more concisely than all those partial sums can be stated.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{2k-1} = \int_0^1 x^{2(k-1)} dx$

Comment: I'm unsure what the question is asking: are you trying to determine whether the series $\sum_k (-1)^{k-1} \frac{1}{9^k (2k-1)}$ converges or are you attempting to compute its sum if it does indeed converges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\arctan(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$ if $|x|< 1.$  Now consider the following shift of the summation index $k\rightarrow k-1.$

> \begin{align} \arctan(x)&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}. \space \text{Now let  $x=\frac{1}{3}$.} \end{align}

> \begin{align} \text{Your final answer should be $6\times\frac{1}{3}\arctan(\frac{1}{3})=2\arctan(\frac{1}{3})\approx 0.64350110879$} \end{align}

Comment: This is a good hint, if the limiting value is sought.  However see the Question and the requests for clarification under it as comments.  If you do wish to assume that the limit is what the Question is about, please carry through and give a definitive Answer.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(\frac 19)^k}{2k-1}=$$
$$\frac 13\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\frac{(\frac 13)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Rewrite the finite sum as $\;\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\frac{\bigl(\tfrac{1}{3}\bigr)^{\!\scriptstyle2k}}{2k-1}$, in the form
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^{2k}}{2k-1}=x\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}$$
and observe that $$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}=\int\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}x^{2(k-1)} \mathrm dx=\int\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{k}x^{2k} \mathrm dx$$
Now, we have the identity
$$\frac 1{1+x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{k}x^{2k}+(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^2}.$$
Can you proceed?